# Ajax-Datatables-Rails: pass params in from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, datatables

I've tried for a few hours to try to pass URI search params in from the controller to my AjaxDatatablesRails class, but no luck. Even if I include them as options in the call to

```
UserDatatable.new(view_context, { PARAMS HERE })
```

No luck. Is it possible with the Ajax-Datatables-Rails gem to pass in Search params from the URI?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to pass something like /users?search="admin" into the datatables class to the get_raw_records method. This doesn't seem to be easily achievable now. And I don't always want to simply call "User.all" from that method in the datatables class.

Comment: How are you attempting to access the values in the params hash? if you're passing the optional hash, you should be able to access the values within your UserDatatable object, using options[:some_key] For example, if within your PARAMS HERE hash, you had something like {thing_id someObject.id} you'd just access it by options[:thing_id]

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to achieve by [this](https://github.com/antillas21/ajax-datatables-rails/issues/93)